# How Kapacitor get Stream in TICK architecure

Tags: influxdb, azure-iot-hub, kapacitor

As per my information, Kapacitor can work on streams or batches. In case of batches, it fetches data from Influxdb and operate on that.

But how does it work with stream. Does it subscribe to InfluxDB or Telegraph. I hope it subscribe to InfluxDB. So in case any client write data to InfluxDb, Kapacitor also receive that data. Is this understanding correct? Or it subscribe directly to Telegraph?

Why this question is important to us is because we want to use Azure IoT hub in place of Telegraph. So, we will read the data from Azure IoT hub and write it to InfluxDb. We hope that we can use Kapacitor Stream here.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Kapacitor subscribes to influxDB. By default if we do not mention what databases to subscribe to, it subscribes to all of them. In Kapacitor's config file you can mention the databases in InfluxDB which you want to subscribe to.